# EF adds extra column for foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using data annotation to have foreign keys. EF successfully builds some columns, but adds extra column for some of the attributes.
Here's my class:

```
public class Class
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column(TypeName = "BIGINT")]
    public Int64 LiIdH { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "BIGINT"), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public Int64 LiIdPeriod { get; set; }
    public virtual ZPeriod ZPeriod { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "SMALLINT"), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public Int16 SWhCode { get; set; }
    public virtual InvtWare InvtWare { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to have `LiIdPeriod` and `SWhCode` as foreign keys. EF adds `LiIdPeriod` as a foreign key but for `SWhCode` it just adds an extra column named `InvtWare_SWhCode`.
How can I solve this problem and have `SwhCode` as foreign key? I prefer data annotation and attributes to fluent API.

Comment: If this is about foreign keys, why did you not show your foreign key tables and describe the relationships ?

Comment: That sounds like a better way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the foreign key to entity framework in two different ways.

1. Using Data Annotation
2. Using Fluent API

**Using Data Annotation**

```
[Column(TypeName = "SMALLINT"), Index(IsUnique = true)]
public Int16 SWhCode { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("SWhCode")] 
public virtual InvtWare InvtWare { get; set; }
```

**Using Fluent API**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Assuming one to many relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().HasRequired(d =>d.InvtWare).WithMany(d => d.Classes).HasForeignKey(d => d.SwhCode);
}
```